# Php post data with $.post to another file

Tags: jquery, sql, post

The issue is i write this script in script.js:

```
$('[name="submitBtn"]').click(function(){
  var nickname= $('[name="username"]').val();
  $.post("functions.php", 
  {
   name: nickname
  },
function(response,status){
  alert("*----Received Data----*\n\nResponse : " + response+"\n\nStatus : " +status);
 })
 })
```

And this on functions.php:

```
if(isset($_POST["name"]))
{
  $name = $_POST["name"];
  mysql_query("INSERT INTO `user`(`user_id`, `username` ) VALUES ('', '$name')");
  echo "Welcome ". $name ."!";
}
```

The problem is that i get alert correctly, seems fine with it. So if i understand correctly, php variable $name gets the value. But it does not insert sql query to database. Also i get error "undefined index name on functions.php" Which i also don't understand. Tried a lot of ways but all the time "name" is undefined index :S

LF help.

Regards.

Edit:

Mysterious things happening.

```
<?php
$test="welcome";
// mysql_query("INSERT INTO `user`(`user_id`, `username` ) VALUES ('', '$test')"); 
if(isset($_POST["name"])){ 
   $name = $_POST["name"];
   $test="Welcome ". $name ."!";
   echo $test;
   mysql_query("INSERT INTO `user`(`user_id`, `username` ) VALUES ('', '$test')"); 
}
?>
```

If i uncomment second line, it DOES insert "welcome" to my table in DB,
but the query in condition have never worked. Also echo $test works also.

Comment: Can you see the name in your alert?

Comment: Try `mysql_query($query) or die( mysql_error() )` to see if there is a wrong name or other mysql errors

Comment: I am sure that something wrong with index "name"

Comment: yes i can see $name in alert.

Answer (score 0):

You need to paste the PHP variable in de string like so:

VALUES ('', '" . $name . "')");

Otherwise your query will contain the variable name and not the PHP value that it should have.

Comment: That's not quite true, as is he is using double quotes `"this is correct $value"` but `'this is not $correct'`

Comment: Neah, i believe it is something to do with jquery script and php file, they understand and do not understand each other somehow in the same time. I mean it alerts correctly the variable but if i want to do anything with it, it says "name" index is undefined.